# Apply Different Rules when clicking on Different Thumbnails (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, gallery

I'm pretty much a newbie on the HTML/CSS realm and have been facing a jquery challenge ever since I started building my first website. I want to create an jquery-powered image gallery, using thumbnails. The tutorial I followed for that matter was Ivan Lazarevic's (http://workshop.rs/2010/07/create-image-gallery-in-4-lines-of-jquery/). I also made use of Stackoverflow's forum through this thread: http://goo.gl/ILzsx.

The code he provides replaces the large image on display with the larger version of the thumbnail that's been clicked. This seems to work pretty smoothly but just for pictures that have the same orientation. The following code appears on two different files, thus establishing a difference between the horizontal and vertical images:

```
   <div id="mainImage">
     <img id="largeImage" src="Images/Projects/UOW/UOWII_large.jpg"/>
   </div>
```

AND:

```
   <div id="mainImageVERTICAL">
     <img id="largeImageVERTICAL" src="Images/Projects/UOW/UOWI_large.jpg" />
   </div>
```

I have created different CSS rules for both the *largeImage* and *largeImageVERTICAL* parameters, depending on whether the image has a portrait or landscape orientation.

```
   #largeImage { 
   position: fixed;
   height: 83%;
   width:auto;
   top: 15%;
   left: 5%;
   }
```

AND:

```
   #largeImageVERTICAL { 
   position: fixed;
   height: 83%;
   width:auto;
   top: 15%;
   left: 36.36%;
   }
```

These two rules just place the images at different points of the screen. However, what I would like to know is how to modify my code so that I can create a page with both portrait and landscape-oriented images applying the CSS rule that belongs to each. Up to now, what I have is what I got from Lazarevic's approach, which is:

```
   $('#thumbs img').click(function(){
   $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
   });
```

This code just replaces the thumbnails with the bigger pictures. As stated, I want to be able to apply the right rule to the right image and I'm assuming this has to be be made through some JS coding, which I know pretty much nothing about.

I would appreciate some help so that I can keep on with this project. Any ideas how to make this work? Maybe a JS function that tells the machine to use one or another CSS rule depending on which image is clicked upon? I'm really stuck here...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [CSS Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries), let the browser do the work.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello but I think this is more related to the actual dimensions of the image than to the device the website is displayed on. Media queries, as far as I'm concerned apply different rules depending on the device and some other factors, but I'm not sure that can help me here. I'd appreciate some further comments on this... ;)

Comment: I just figured that out and deleted my answer. lol I thought you were trying to display it differently based on the orientation of the browser. I need more coffee

Comment: Gotcha! haha Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

Use a HTML5 `data-*` attribute to specify which of the `<img>` elements should be updated. So:

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <img src="img.jpg" data-large="largeImage"/>
    <img src="anotherimg.jpg" data-large="largeImageVERTICAL"/>
</div>
```

Then:

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(e) {
    var imageId = $(this).attr('data-large'),
        newSrc = this.src.replace('thumb', 'large');
    $('#' + imageId).attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

Or, use the dimensions of the thumbnail to determine whether it's portrait or landscape:

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        height = $this.height(),
        width = $this.width(),
        newSrc = this.src.replace('thumb', 'large');
    var imageId = (height > width) ? 'largeImageVERTICAL' : 'largeImage';
    $('#' + imageId).attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

In either case, you'll probably need to hide the other, unused `<img>` element so that you don't have the previously selected image for the other orientation displayed.

One way to achieve this would be:

```
var alternateImageId = (imageId === 'largeImage') ? 'largeImageVERTICAL' : 'largeImage';
$('#' + alternateImageId).hide();
```

Add the above two lines to the `click` event handler above, and call `.show()` after calling `.attr('src', ...)`.

Comment: Cheers! This definitely makes sense to me, I just could not work out how to make the <img> element hide since I have two different id's for both the portrait and the landscape images respectively... As far as I've read, this can be achieved through a CSS rule and some JS code, but, again, this just seems to be beyond my understanding so far. Any ideas?

Comment: @mctosp You need to get the `id` for the element you need to hide, which will be the "other one" based on the `id` for the element you're updating. Edited the answer with some code to do that.

Comment: I do understand the hide/show thing. My code looks like this:

`$('#thumbnails img').click(function(e) {
    var imageId = $(this).attr('data-large'),
        newSrc = this.src.replace('thumb', 'large');
    $('#' + imageId).attr('src', newSrc);
 $('#' + imageId).show();
 var alternateImageId = (imageId === 'largeImage') ? 'largeImageVERTICAL' : 'largeImage';
 $('#' + alternateImageId).hide();
 });`

However, I still cannot figure out how to relate this function to the actual large image, which had its own _largeImage_ / _largeImageVERTICAL_ before.

Comment: I mean, in your response _largeImage_ and _largeImageVERTICAL_ correspond to the image id's of the thumbnails, right? But I had used those id's for the large images, not the thumbnails. In my CSS I apply rules to both _largeImage_ and _largeImageVERTICAL_ id's, but that should correspond to both large Image containers or I should have just one? I'm not quite getting this. Hope my doubts are well-expressed and sound reasonable enough...

Comment: @mctosp No, I'm using those as the `id`s of the large images; the way I understood the question was one was intended to display portrait images and the other displays landscape images. However, if you click the thumbnail for a portrait image - and update `largeImageVERTICAL` - if you next click on a landscape image - and update `largeImage` - you don't want `largeImageVERTICAL` to be visible otherwise you end up displaying two at a time.

Comment: Feel free to correct me if I've misunderstood any part of what you're trying to achieve, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use class not id.

```
#largeImage{ 
   top: 15%;
   width:auto;
   height: 83%;
   position: fixed;
}
.portrait{ 
   left: 36.36%;
}
.landscape{ 
   left: 5%;
}
```

**js**

```
$('#largeImage').on('load', function () {
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.width() < that.height()) {
        that.addClass('portrait');
    } else {
        that.addClass('landscape');
    }
});
$('#thumbs').on('click', 'img', function () {
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
});
```

Comment: I've been working on this for a bit but I just can't come up with a right solution for replacing the image according to the class using the right id as you suggested. I'm quite novel with JS so I'm not really sure how I should be writing that order. I guess I should tweak the old jquery code a little... 



Can you give me a hand with this? Thanks for the quick answer, btw!

Comment: OK, my bad I didn't get what was your idea at the beginning.
So a few words about the code. The **thumbnails** no big changes there as in the tutorial just more efficient click listener binding, use it that way. About the large one ... every time when it's loaded according to what is bigger the `width` or the `height` we give it a class `landscape` or `portrait` which are predefined left positioning as the css provided by you in the first place.

Comment: Use jquery 1.7.1 or higher because of `.on()`